Value error in passing batch_input_shape Argument in Keras Embedded Layer
I am having trouble with passing "batch_input_shape" in Jupyter Lab and VScode as well.
### Defining the RNN Model ###
def LSTM(rnn_units):
  return tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
    rnn_units,
    return_sequences=True,
    recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform',
    recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
    stateful=True,
  )

def build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units, batch_size):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, **batch_input_shape=[batch_size,None])**,
    LSTM(rnn_units),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
  ])
  return model


model = build_model(len(vocab), embedding_dim=256, rnn_units=1024, batch_size=32)


I currently have the same issue (and am also doing the MIT deeplearning course). The reason for the issue is (I think) because there's been a change to the Keras API. I am not sure what the alternative keyword arg would be, and I haven't found anything yet.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding
The embedding layer doesn't have anything at all relating to batch_input_shape. Unfortunately, I have very little knowledge on the Keras API and deep learning in general. I will keep posted if I find a solution.
EDIT: Found a work-around that worked; Adding keras.Input as the first item in the Sequential model fixed the issue. Also make sure to edit your tf.keras.layers.Embedding, and remove the batch_input_shape parameter:
### Defining the RNN Model ###
def LSTM(rnn_units):
  return tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
    rnn_units,
    return_sequences=True,
    recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform',
    recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
    stateful=True,
  )

def build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units, batch_size):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input(shape=shape, batch_size=batch_size),
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim),
    LSTM(rnn_units),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
  ])
  return model


model = build_model(len(vocab), embedding_dim=256, rnn_units=1024, batch_size=32)

Hopefully this works for you (or anyone) without issue.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

Sorry, needed to find a fix for the issue but I still wanted to provide some details of what I knew as a bare minimum.

Your edit looks good, if your interested, batch_input_shape was (presumably) never meant to be added and looking through the Internet Archive the keras documentation never listed it. Looking through github as far back as 2015 it was never included in the actual Embedding layer code as it simply doesn't make sense. Instead it's most likely just the result of batch_input_shape being inherited in any case as your edit points out an input layer is best suited. What can be said is that your course seems to be pretty dated

@35308 I certainly think that the course is dated to a great extent: I've been trying to find a good way to learn how to get into deep learning, so I thought that the MIT course might've been good. The lectures were certainly helpful, but I might just have to skip the lab. Thank you for the additional information though, because that is far different than what I had expected.
